# How to slice from a certain variable in raw input

Tags: python-3.x

Say for example, the raw input is:

```
... BEGIN 18.2_1894:19.8E,78.0S HBKLKL END ...
```

and I want to slice out different sections that lie between `BEGIN` and `END`, ignoring everything before `BEGIN` and after `END`, where `...` is a unspecified or changing amount of characters before `BEGIN` and `END`. i.e. ignore everything besides that between `BEGIN` and `END` and only slice parts of what is in between.

How can I get just those characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regex:

The `(.*)` captures any character, zero or more times, which occurs between `BEGIN` and `END`. Then the `res.group(1)` references the first capture.

```
import re
data = "... BEGIN 18.2_1894:19.8E,78.0S HBKLKL END ..."
res  = re.search('BEGIN(.*)END', data)
print res.group(1)

print
print "Now, you can also capture specific parts with a regex..."
print

res  = re.search('BEGIN ([0-9\.]+)_([0-9]+):([0-9\.A-Z]+),([0-9\.A-Z]+) ([A-Z]+) END', data)

print res.group(1) # 18.2
print res.group(2) # 1894
print res.group(3) # 19.8E
print res.group(4) # 78.0S
print res.group(5) # HBKLKL

print
print "Or if you really want to use substrings...."
print

pos = data.index("BEGIN") + 5;
print data[(pos+3):(pos+9)]     # .2_189
```

Comment: What if i want to capture particular characters by their numerical position following "BEGIN"? ie I want to capture the 3-9th characters after begin?

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
import re

teststr = ".... BEGIN 18.2_1894:19.8E,78.0S HBKLKL END ..."
match = re.search(r'Begin.*End',teststr, re.IGNORECASE)
print(match.group(0))
```

this includes "begin" and "end" in output. let me know if you want to remove "begin" and "end" too.

Comment: @varlogtim , yes, I didn't update my one after I saw your post. You already gave out result. :)